# identifying source of 'conversion failed error'

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

i am trying to execute a query:

```
select 
distinct
billed.accn_id,
payors.PAYOR_PRIORITY,
payors.PAYOR_NAME,
payors.PAYOR_ID,
payorconfig.PAYOR_GROUP,
payorconfig.CONTACT1_ADDR1,
payorconfig.CONTACT1_ADDR2,
payorconfig.CONTACT1_CITY,
payorconfig.CONTACT1_STATE,
payorconfig.CONTACT1_ZIPCODE,
payorconfig.CONTACT1_PHONE,
payorconfig.CONTACT1_FAX,
payorconfig.CONTACT1_EMAIL,
patient.PT_ID,
patient.PT_ADDR1,
patient.PT_ADDR2,
patient.PT_CITY,
patient.PT_ST_ID,
patient.PT_ZIPCODE,
patient.PT_HOME_PHM

from accn_billed_procedures billed
left outer join accn_payors payors
on payors.accn_id=billed.accn_id

left outer join payor_config payorconfig
on payorconfig.payor_id=payors.x_payor_id

left outer join accn_demographics demos
on billed.accn_id = demos.accn_id

left outer join patient_demographics patient
on demos.pt_id=patient.pt_id
```

and getting this error:

> Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 Conversion failed when converting
>   the varchar value '121CLAIMS' to data type int.

how am i supposed to know exactly what is causing this?

is it possible to get this error on a join where the data types of the joining columns do not match ?

thank you so much for your guidance and help

Comment: Yes, are any of these `id` columns not numeric? That's where I would start.

Comment: why is ssms so stupid? why can't it identify where the prob is?

Comment: Why do you think this is Management Studio's fault? You'll get the same error if you submit this query from C# or ASP or PowerShell. What would be nice is if SQL Server rejected a query like this outright. `Msg 2066 Why are you joining on columns that are not the same data type??!??!?` But no, SQL Server is very forgiving of bad design, and will give you the benefit of the doubt until runtime that you might be storing only ints in your varchar column... The fix, of course, is to use the right data type and/or the right join semantics. You don't seem to have done either.

Comment: i am  saying why cant it say column x and column y cannot be joined since they are different data types

Comment: also one time when i was doing a bulk insert on 50 tables each having around 40 fields it said that there was a type mismatch - well why cant it provide exactly where the mismatch occurred?

Comment: also, c# will definitely tell you exactly where your error occurred

Comment: They are getting better about this (e.g. Pk/uq violations in 2008 R2 tell you the first value that was violated), but they're not perfect. They're very reluctant to "fix" error messages because they can break compatibility for customers who have written code to consume and parse the errors.

Comment: ohoh very interesting! i didnt realize this

Comment: sorry i didnt mean that. i meant that when you compile code that has errors in it, it will tell you exactly where the error occurred

Comment: a separate question for you, aaron, as you can see in my query i am doing a bunch of left outer joins, can you please point me to a resource to help me understand exactly what is happening when i do joining?

Comment: You're not compiling code, you're running a query (this is more like runtime - SQL Server doesn't magically know in advance that a conflict is going to occur until you run it). When you compile a C# program and a user executes it, isn't it up to you, not C# itself, how much information you expose to the end user when an exception occurs?

Comment: what i am failing to  understand is let's say we have 3 different datasets: A, B, C. i would like to join all three. how do i decide whether to join A to C and then to B or A to B and then to C?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12226/discussion-between---and-aaron-bertrand)

Comment: @AaronBertrand you still there man?

Comment: Here are a few tutorials that a quick search yielded - http://www.sql-tutorial.net/SQL-JOIN.asp http://www.ezineasp.net/post/Types-of-Joins-in-Sql-Server-2005.aspx http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/04/13/sql-server-introduction-to-joins-basic-of-joins/

Comment: thanks so much. and am i correct in doing LEFT OUTER joins for all my tables since i always want to include the left side even if it does not match on the right table on anything?

Comment: That's not really an easy question for someone outside of your app to answer. Do all of the joins make sense? Are the tables really related (I'm guessing from the error message that they're not)? When there is a match, do all the columns on that joined row belong together? I'm not asking for answers, these are questions you need to ask yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just taking a stab at this, but because your query has nothing complex in the select statement - the only logical place where a conversion is being attempted would be inside one of your join qualifiers: "on payors.accn_id=billed.accn_id" , etc.

I suspect one of your tables is actually storing the field : accn_id or pt_id , etc as a VARCHAR (or maybe a VARCHAR value was stored in that column by accident)

In any event it seems the the data is suspect ..  on one side you have an int, the other a string. Your best bet would be to make all ID fields of type VARCHAR, because trying to convert them in during the query can be devastating to performance

hope that helps!